# "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DBAccess", referenced from:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, sdk

Trying to build my program and getting the following error. Don't see anything obvious. All my import statements seem correct:

Undefined symbols:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DBAccess", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-DBAccess in LocationsViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of problem usually means that the linker isn't finding the class (if your imports are wrong you only get a lexing warning).

Check to make sure that your project is properly linked to whatever uses `DBAccess` and that `DBAccess.m/h` is included in the output.